# Django 2.0.5 display different queryset result with the CBV listview

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Hi: I am trying to build a staff directory where user can filter view by department. I have the department list displayed in a dropdown button but cannot figure out how to properly pass the user selection to the listview in the views.py Please see the code below.

models.py

```
class Department(models.Model):
  department = models.CharField(max_length = 20, unique = True)
 def __str__(self):
    return self.department

class EmployeeList(models.Model):
  department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True, blank = True)
```

views.py

```
class EmployeeOutput(ListView):
  model = models.EmployeeList
  context_object_name = 'employee_list'
  template_name = 'employee_list.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(EmployeeOutput, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['filter_list'] = models.Department.objects.values_list('department', flat = True)
    return context

class FilterDepartment(ListView):
  model = models.EmployeeList
  context_object_name = 'employee_list'
  template_name = 'employee_list.html'

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(FilterDepartment, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['filter_list'] = models.Department.objects.values_list('department', flat = True)
    context['department_filter'] = models.EmployeeList.objects.filter(department_id = 3)
    return context
```

employee_list.html

```
<table class = 'table table-striped table-hover' id = 'my_table'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><button type="button" class = ' btn btn-info' onclick = 'sortTable(0)'>Name</button></th>
            <th><button type="button" class = ' btn btn-info' onclick = 'sortTableNumbers(1)'>Phone Ex</button></th>
            <th><button type="button" class = ' btn btn-info' onclick = 'sortTable(2)'>Email</button></th>
            <th>
              <div class="btn-group dropright">
                <button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Department
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" onclick = 'sortTable(3)'><b>Sort Department</b></a>
                  <h6 class="dropdown-header">Filter by:</h6>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  {% for running in filter_list%}
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'employee:department_filter' %}"><b>{{running}}</b></a>
                  {% endfor %}
                </div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th><button type="button" class = ' btn btn-info' onclick = 'sortTable(4)'>Remote Access</button></th>
            <th>Cell Phone</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% if department_filter %}
            {% for EL in department_filter %}
              <tr>
                <td>{{EL.first_name}} {{EL.last_name}}</td>
                <td>{{EL.phone_ex}}</td>
                <td> <a href="mailto:{{EL.email}}">{{EL.email}}</a></td>
                <td>{{EL.department}}</td>
                <td>{{EL.remote_access}}</td>
                <td>{{EL.cell}}</td>
              </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          {% else %}
            {% for EL in employee_list %}
              <tr>
                <td>{{EL.first_name}} {{EL.last_name}}</td>
                <td>{{EL.phone_ex}}</td>
                <td> <a href="mailto:{{EL.email}}">{{EL.email}}</a></td>
                <td>{{EL.department}}</td>
                <td>{{EL.remote_access}}</td>
                <td>{{EL.cell}}</td>
              </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

I can properly display the entire staff with 'employee_list'. I can show a list of current department in the dropdown button with 'filter_list'. When user clicked on any of the selection, it always shows the same result since 'department_list' is hard coded to department_id = 3. What I need to find out is how to pass in the ID with href as

```
{% url 'employee:department_filter' dept=running.id %}
```

with url.py

```
path('filter/<int:dept>', views.FilterDepartment.as_view(), name = 'department_filter'),
```

I am struggling to find out how to pass 'dept' into the 'FilterDepartment' view. Maybe there is a better way to do this or I am just missing the last piece to make this happen. Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you

suggestion by @dirkgroten

employee_list.html

```
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'employee:department_filter' dept=running.id %}"><b>{{running}}</b></a>
          {% if object_list %}
            {% for EL in object_list %}
              <tr>
                <td><a href="{% url 'employee:employee_update' pk=EL.pk %}">{{EL.first_name}} {{EL.last_name}}</a></td>
                <td>{{EL.phone_ex}}</td>
                <td> <a href="mailto:{{EL.email}}">{{EL.email}}</a></td>
                <td>{{EL.department}}</td>
                <td>{{EL.remote_access}}</td>
                <td>{{EL.cell}}</td>
              </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
path('filter/<int:dept>/', views.FilterDepartment.as_view(), name = 'department_filter'),
```

views.py

```
class FilterDepartment(ListView):
model = models.EmployeeList
context_object_name = 'employee_list'
template_name = 'employee_list.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(FilterDepartment, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['filter_list'] = models.Department.objects.values_list('department', flat = True)
    return context

def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
    return super().get_queryset().filter(department_id=self.kwargs['dept'])
```

working solution:

employee_list.html

```
{% for running in filter_list%}
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'employee:department_filter' running %}"><b>{{running}}</b></a>
                  {% endfor %}
  {% if object_list %}
            {% for EL in object_list %}
              <tr>
                <td><a href="{% url 'employee:employee_update' pk=EL.pk %}">{{EL.first_name}} {{EL.last_name}}</a></td>
                <td>{{EL.phone_ex}}</td>
                <td> <a href="mailto:{{EL.email}}">{{EL.email}}</a></td>
                <td>{{EL.department}}</td>
                <td>{{EL.remote_access}}</td>
                <td>{{EL.cell}}</td>
              </tr>
```

urls.py

```
path('filter/<department>/', views.FilterDepartment.as_view(), name = 'department_filter'),
```

views.py

```
class FilterDepartment(ListView):
model = models.EmployeeList
context_object_name = 'employee_list'
template_name = 'employee_list.html'
    #if missing, it is looking for EmployeeList_list.html
    #employee_list.pk used in empllyee_list.html

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(FilterDepartment, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['filter_list'] = models.Department.objects.values_list('department', flat = True)
    # context['department_filter'] = models.EmployeeList.objects.filter(department_id = self.kwargs['dept'])
    return context

def get_queryset(self):
    return super(FilterDepartment, self).get_queryset().filter(department__department=self.kwargs['department'])
```

Comment: `<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'employee:department_filter' %}">` should be `<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'employee:department_filter' dept=running.id %}">` in your template.

Comment: In a `ListView`, the place to apply a filter is to override the `get_queryset()` method and return `super().get_queryset().filter(department_id=self.kwargs['dept'])`. (the `dept` from the url is assigned to `self.kwargs`). You should not have to override `get_context_data()` unless you need more than the `object_list` in your template.

Comment: hi @dirkgroten , thank you. I understand your first comment. Would you please be more specific about how to modify my views.py as in where do I put 'super().get_queryset().filter(department_id=self.kwargs['dept']'. Should I get rid of get_context_data all together? how do I pass in the 'filter_list' that way?

Comment: No, keep get_context_data() indeed to pass the `filter_list`. Add the `def get_queryset(self)` method override to your view, that should return the queryset/list of objects you want to display in your view. Remember after that that the list of objects is `object_list` in your context, not `department_filter`.

Comment: hi @dirkgroten. Thank you. I re-posted my views.py and your other suggestion.  I am not sure if this is what you mean. Sorry, I might bite off more than I can chew but this really helps me understanding/reading the official documents. thanks

Comment: Yes that’s what I meant. Does it work? If not what’s the error. A good place to dive deeper into generic Django views is [here](http://ccbv.co.uk/). Gives you a better understanding of `ListView` for example.

Comment: Hi @dirkgroten. holy molly, see my working solutions. never expect solving anything by reading docs... but here we go. I greatly appreciated your guidance. It definitely puts me on the right track. Thank you so much. How do I give you something like a  thumb up on stack overflow?

Comment: I'll add a brief response below that you can mark as correct

Comment: hi @dirkgroten one more followup question. I was using the tag 'object_list' in my template to show the filtered employee view. This tag name has no resemblance to the class FilterDepartment. the context_object_name is still 'employee_list'. See my last post on views.py. what is the relationship between these two name? I believed that 'object_list' replaced the 'employee_list' if so, is there a way to customize the tag name of this filter to be something else than 'object list'?  in case I am using multiple class on the same template. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ListView`'s `get_queryset()` method to filter the list of objects you want to display. This will add `object_list` to the context in the template. Only use `get_context_data()` to add additional information to the context.

```
class FilterDepartment(ListView):
    # properties like model and template_name
    # context_object_name can be used if you want to call the list something else than 'object_list' in your context

    def get_queryset(self):
         return super().get_queryset().filter(department_id=self.kwargs['dept'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)  # this will already include object_list
         context['filter_list'] = models.Department.objects.values_list('department', flat = True)
         return context
```

The Django documentation on `ListView` is quite concise and makes it difficult to really understand which methods to override. A better place to understand Django's generic class based views is [here](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.list/ListView/).